# each() function updating all elements with the same value

Tags: jquery, each

Trying to make this function work but it's not really working for each `.travel`. Every travel has the same result

```
$(".travel").each(function() {
  var land = $(".invisible .land").text();
  $(".land-vorschau").html(land);
});
```

Could you help, please?

Comment: If you're trying to get the text of `.invisible .land` inside each `.travel`, you need to add the context `this` to your selector : `$(".invisible .land",this)`

Comment: You need to use DOM traversal to relate the `.land` and `.land-vorschau` elements to the current `.travel`. We can show you how to do that, but we need to see the associated HTML too.

Comment: Please click the `<>` snippet editor and add relevant HTML and CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$(this)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in your context

```
$('.travel').each(function() {
  var land = $(this).find('.invisible .land').text();
  $(this).find('.land-vorschau').html(land);
});
```

Comment: working perfect, thx!

Answer (score 0):

To select within descendants, use `.find()`, like so:

```
$('.travel').each(function(i, e) {
  var land = $(e).find('.invisible .land').text();
  $(e).find('.land-vorschau').html(land);
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: e.find is not a function

Comment: Sorry, updated the answer with `$(e)`